# Why does AsyncTask's execute() must be invoked on the UI thread even though AsyncTask uses Looper.getMainLooper() in internalHandler?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Why must the `AsyncTask`'s method `execute(Params...)` invoked on the UI thread as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29) even though AsyncTask uses Looper.getMainLooper() in internalHandler?

I tried creating the task and calling its execute(Params...) from a background thread and it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why must the `AsyncTask`'s method `execute(Params...)` invoked on the UI thread as stated in the documentation even though AsyncTask uses Looper.getMainLooper() in internalHandler?

*Why* can be a philosophical question sometimes... I inspected `AsyncTask` code for Android API 25 and the code itself does not give us a straight answer. Only the person who developed this class knows why.

But, what the code do tell us is that it could forward calls from a background thread to the UI thread, but it doesn't. So the developer didn't have the expertise to do that, or was lazy, or wanted to enforce a pattern, or whatever.

> I tried creating the task and calling its execute(Params...) from a background thread and it works fine.

Mind that it worked, but it's not guaranteed to always work. Multithreading programming is pretty tricky, and its debugging can be the hell on earth.

In the code inspection I noticed that the `onPreExecute()` call is done in the same thread that invokes `execute(Params...)`. So, if you call `execute(Params...)` in a background thread, it will break the invariant that `onPreExecute()` runs on UI thread.

Comment: i 'd really appreciate if the downvoter expressed his or her motives in the comments

Comment: I upvoted this answer as especially the last part is quite a good answer to the question.